# Movie or TV show where a man telepathically saves child from coma

Tags: story-identification, telepathy

I am trying to identify a program I saw on American television sometime in the late 90's or early 00's.  I am unsure if it was a movie being shown on TV or just an episode of a TV series, but it was a live-action drama.  Here are the details from a scene that I can remember:

- There is a male telepath/psychic with a female companion who are at some sort of medical care facility.  The facility is not a hospital but instead more of a sanitarium or long-term care community.  There is also an old woman present who suffers from a painful disease.
- The man is visiting a child who is in a coma and is asked to use telepathy to try to bring the child out of the coma.  For some reason the man initially cannot establish a telepathic connection with the child, but he finds that he can communicate with the child if he uses a telepathic link with the old woman's pain as some sort of catalyst.
- Writhing in the pain he now shares with the old woman, the man finds himself in a vision of being in a dark tunnel with a light at the end.  The child is standing between the man and the light.  The child is crying, saying it is frightened, and is walking towards the light.  The man calls to the child and tells it not to enter the light.  As the child turns around begins to move towards the man, water gushes into the tunnel and immediately submerges both the man and the child.  The man swims to the child and pushes it above the surface of the water which causes the child to regain consciousness in the real world.
- As those in the real world are observing the child's recovery and speaking to the child, the camera pans to the man who becomes unresponsive and collapses.  The scene cuts back to the vision where the man is now sinking further underneath surface of the water.  A young boy suddenly appears in the vision, swims to the man, and pushes him above the surface of the water at which point the man regains consciousness in the real world.  I seem to remember that the young boy is a friend or sibling who died when the man was a child, but I am not sure.
- I have very fuzzy memories that the old woman's name is a short name like Lucy or Ruby.  The child may have been a young girl, and the scene in the real world may have taken place on an outdoor patio.  I could be very wrong on these details though.

Comment: This sounds like "The Other Side" from The Outer Limits season 5 (1999)

Comment: @AaronGullison  Very good guess.  Lots of shared elements, but this is unfortunately not it.  In particular, it is missing the use of pain to establish the telepathic connection and the tunnel _completely_ flooding.  There was also not any external technology used to do the telepathic link.  It was via concentration and/or physical contact.